# test on SELECT Menu values

Tags: php

I have a select menu, and i'd like to make a mysql query depending on the chosen value.
I have created a function that compares the selected value with, 
here's my form of select menu:

```
<form method="POST"  action = "choose-type.php">
    <select name="Value" SIZE=1>
        <option value="'Clothes'">CLOTHES
        <option value="'Wine'">WINE
        <option value="'Bread'">BREAD
        <option value="'Milk'">MILK
    </select>
    <div>
      <input Value="submit" align="middle" > 
    </div>
</form>

<?php    
   $Value = $_POST['Value'];
   $DST = array('\'CLOTHES\'','\'WINE\'');
   function type() {
    $TYPE2 = ' ';
    if (($Value == $DST[0]) or ($Value == $DST[1])) {
           $TYPE2 = 'first';
        }
        else {
            $TYPE2 = 'second';
        }
    return $TYPE2;
   }
```

My code doesn't work :/ it always returns first even if i choose 'milk for example' can someone correct my code please ???

Comment: Already answered, but it might be worth closing the options with </option> even though in this case it is not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to pass `$Value,$DST` inside function

```
function type() {
    $Value = $_POST['Value'];
    $DST = array('\'CLOTHES\'','\'WINE\'');
    $TYPE2 = ' ';
    if (($Value == $DST[0]) or ($Value == $DST[1])) {
       $TYPE2 = 'first';
    }
    else {
        $TYPE2 = 'second';
    }
    return $TYPE2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should double-check what's coming in on the $_POST before you run your function. It looks like your case is causing problems; you're comparing 'CLOTHES' == 'Clothes', which isn't the same. Add the die() line below so you can see what the form sends and act accordingly. Obviously remove it again when you know what to do.

```
die(var_dump($_POST));
$Value = $_POST['Value'];

$DST = array('\'CLOTHES\'','\'WINE\'');
function type() {
 $TYPE2 = ' ';
 if (($Value == $DST[0]) or ($Value == $DST[1])) {
        $TYPE2 = 'first';
     }
     else {
         $TYPE2 = 'second';
      }
 return $TYPE2;
```